# Table represented by array of arrays doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of arrays that will represent a table of numbers. For some reason, the first row is copying the second row. Here is my code:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    rows = 2,
    cols = 4,
    i,
    j,
    row = [],
    table = [];
for (i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j += 1) {
        row[j] = numbers[i * cols + j];
        console.log(row[j]);
        console.log(row);
    }
    console.log(row);
    table[i] = row;
}
console.log(table);
```

As you can see, even while on the first row (i === 0), writing out the current number is correct (1 or 2 or 3 or 4), but writing out the entire row is writing numbers from the second row (5 or 5, 6 or 5, 6, 7 or 5, 6, 7, 8). Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply make an array of arrays? `var numbers = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];`

Comment: That's what I'm doing but the numbers and the size of the table is dynamic so I can't just declare it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only declaring `var row=[]` ones.

Therefore you keep writing to the same variable which will keep overwriting the previous values.

Declare it inside the loop instead to keep re-setting it.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    rows = 2,
    cols = 4,
    i,
    j,
    //row = [], not here - move to loop
    table = [];
for (i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    var row = []; // declare row each time!

    for (j = 0; j < cols; j += 1) {
        row[j] = numbers[i * cols + j];
    }

    table[i] = row;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yRf2h/) - re-set row each time

---

Comment: Thanks, this works. I thought that the rows would get overwritten each iteration of i but I guess not. I still don't really understand why the rows differed on the first iteration (row[j] was 1 but row was [5]). I'm guessing it has to do with hoisting?

Comment: @user2872841: `table[i] = row` is assigning a **reference** to `row` to `table[i]` not copying the actual values. At the time your `console.log(row)` is running within the loop you are only printing out `row`'s values as they are at this moment of time. As you are not re-declaring `row` each time the values get over-written and hence the **reference** you store in `table[i]` is pointing each time to the latest values. By declaring `row` inside the loop you are creating each time a different `row` object so `table[i]` is receiving the **reference** of a different `row` object each time.

Comment: Aha I didn't think of that; thanks for the explanation. Just curious though, if `console.log(row)` prints the latest values of row, how come it doesn't first print [5, 6, 7, 8] or maybe [5, 2, 3, 4]? How come it only prints [5]?

Comment: @user2872841: I added some text to your original code's logging and it always prints out the current value within each iteration as expected for each console.command. See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RWZL2/) with formatted console logs. You can see `console.log(row[j]);` inside the `j` loop goes up from `1` to `8`, `console.log(row);` inside the `j` right below it starts with `[1]`, then `[1, 2]` and eventually when you go around for the second `row`, `j` will be re-set to `0` and the new values are injected back from the start, hence you see `[5, 2, 3, 4]` then `[5, 6, 3, 4]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are always referencing the same rows array, you need a new one on each iteration:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    rows = 2,
    cols = 4,
    i,
    j,
    table = [];
for (i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    table[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j += 1) {
        table[i][j] = numbers[i * cols + j];
    }
}

console.log(table);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too! I might go for this one because I don't even need to declare row.